# Sufficient conditions to have $f' = O(f(x)/x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, asymptotics

Suppose $f$ a nonnegative real-valued function, non-decreasing, $O(x^m)$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant 0}$ and $C^1$, with $f'$ being monotonic and nonnegative. Are this sufficient conditions to have $f'(x) = O(f(x)/x)$ as $x\to +\infty$?

I've took these hypotheses from known cases, like $\sqrt[3]{x}$, $\sqrt{x}\log{x}$, $x/{\log{x}}$, etc., but I was unable to prove this in general, not even assuming $f = O(x)$ and $f'$ bounded.

Comment: as $x\to$ what?

Comment: $x\to +\infty$, sorry.

Comment: You could start from the fact that $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \leq \frac{C}{x}$ implies $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \log f(x) - C\log x \right) \leq 0$. Roughly speaking, $x \mapsto \log \frac{f(x)}{x^C}$ is a decreasing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such condition is that $f$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere and that $f'$ be locally integrable and have *regular variation* at infinity.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ A function $g$ is said to have *regular variation of index $\alpha$* at infinity if for all $y > 0$,

$$\lim_{x \to + \infty} \frac{g(xy)}{g(x)} = y^\alpha.$$

It is said to have regular variation (at infinity) if it has regular variation of index $\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Functions with regular variation of index $0$ are also called functions with [slow variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function).

For instance, rational functions have regular variation (of integer index); logarithms have slow variation ; $x \mapsto x^\alpha$ has regular variation of index $\alpha$; products of functions with regular variation have regular variation...

Then the result follows from Karamata's theorem.

Note that regular variation often include a measurability condition, which is always true for a derivative. I think we can do without the "locally integrable" condition here, but I don't have the Bingham-Goldie-Teugels with me to check.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but this was exactly what I needed hahaha, Proposition 2.10.3 of Bingham et al. was exactly the result I was looking for. Also, this a beautiful book! I've been reading since March of this year but just came across this result last month. Thank you very much for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

[OP changed the question since this answer was posted]

Have you tried $f(x)=e^x$? It's a smooth nonnegative nondecreasing function with $f'(x)=e^x$ which is monotonic and nonnegative, but
$$e^x\ne O(e^x/x)$$

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking in functions with polynomial growth, I forgot to mention that. I'll fix my question.

Comment: Well, I considered this case too! Note that $f'$ is not monotonic in that sketch of $f$. But that idea of making $f'$ grow in a strange way may be fruitful for a counterexample...

Comment: @Alufat Right, I forgot about the monotonicity. I've reverted it to the old version for now. I'll think about it some more.